# Import test cases to Testlink

Tags: xml, excel, import, testlink

I'm trying to import test cases to Testlink. The xml file is from excel. The fields I have are:

```
Name,
Summary, 
Stepactions, 
Expectedresults
```

However, I only see Name and Summary in Testlink. Stepactions and expectedresults are not imported. What's wrong??

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 5):

Not sure what your xml looks like, but this works for me.  I'm using Testlink version 1.9.7

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testcases>
<testcase name="NAME_OF_TESTCASE">
    <summary>Description of test case</summary>
    <preconditions>some pre conditions</preconditions>
    <execution_type>2</execution_type>
    <steps>
        <step>
            <step_number>1</step_number>
            <actions>Do a thing</actions>
            <expectedresults>This is what to expect</expectedresults>
            <execution_type>2</execution_type>
        </step>
        <step>
            <step_number>2</step_number>
            <actions>Do another thing</actions>
            <expectedresults>more expected results</expectedresults>
            <execution_type>1</execution_type>
        </step>
    </steps>
    <custom_fields>
        <custom_field>
            <name>some_cf_name</name>
            <value>some_cf_value</value>
        </custom_field>
    </custom_fields>
</testcase>
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at https://github.com/MrBricodage/TestLink--ImportExcelMacro

- It has pdf documents which describes how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

It took three days to find this solution only u have to do is,

- Download Ex-Converter from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ex-converter/files/Executable%20Applications/EX-Converter_1_2_1_rel/) Works fine only with Windows-7.
- Create `TestCases.xlsx` excel file with fields `Name, Importance, Summary, Preconditions, Actions, Expected-results`
- Open downloaded application `Ex-Converter.exe`
- Give path of `TestCases.xlsx` file and new file `TestCases.xml`
- Click on `Convert`
- On TestLink > `Test specification` > `Your Project name` > `Create test suite` > inside test suite `Import` > `TestCases.xml`
- You are DONE :)